# Querying MapR with db-shell - where clause

Tags: mapr

The following works:

```
mapr dbshell 'find /sourcepath --q {"$select":"source","$where":{"$and":[{"$eq":{"status":"file_LOAD_START"}}]}}'
```

The following works too:

```
mapr dbshell 'find /sourcepath --q {"$select":"source","$where":{"$and":[{"$eq":{"car_id":"number"}}]}}'
```

But the following does not work

```
mapr dbshell 'find /sourcepath --q {"$select":"source","$where":{"$and":[{"$eq":{"status":"file_LOAD_START"}}, {"$eq":{"car_id":"number"}}]}}'
```

The error message states

"You cannot specify '{"$eq":{"car_id":"number"}}]}}' as another value for the default ('') option in a single command.
You already provided '/sourcepath' earlier.
Did you forget to add quotes around the value of another option?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it did not work where white spaces.

Removing the whitespace between {"status":"file_LOAD_START"}}, and {"$eq":{"car_id":"number"}}]}}' solved the problem